# npm start Angular2 just won't start

Tags: angular, npm, npm-start

So i run the npm start command in the command prompt and i get this error, i saw the other posts but none of them had the solution to my problem. Here's the error i get.

This is the command error i get--

[image]

I already tried installing the latest npm but didn't work.
I need to mentioned that is just stopped working today, it has worked the past days. It's just when i run the npm start command it wont start anymore and I can't seem to figure it out how to fix it.

Output Log file
[image]

Comment: `npm -v` and `node -v` and paste it here.

Comment: npm -v : 4.2.0 , node -v :6.9.5

Comment: Did you install typescript compiler globally?

Comment: @echonax i just did it, npm install -g typescript, but didn't work

Comment: did you install all the dependencies? npm install

Comment: @pixelbits yes i did, i ran npm install , then i ran npm start, and it worked(yesterday), i worked all day .

Comment: Try to remove the node_modules folder then run npm clean: npm upgrade; npm install

Comment: Post the log output (the error lines should be enough)

Comment: @JeremLeBlond that is not working, there doesn't even exists a npm clean or npm upgrade command, at least that's what it's telling me.

Comment: @Tinwor this is the file

Comment: My bad 'npm cache clean'

Answer (score 0):

I had this error few times !

Remove your node_modules folder then run npm cache clean;npm rebuild; npm install

Comment: that is not working, there doesn't even exists a npm clean command, at least that's what it's telling me.

Comment: Try npm cache clean and npm rebuild

Comment: still not working, tried first to delete the file, then to run npm cache clean and then npm rebuild, or npm cache clean, then npm upgrade and npm install, still not working.

Comment: Maybe you should try to reinstall tsc ? `npm uninstall tsc`

Comment: i tried it already(reinstall), doesn't work. But the odd thing is if i make a new Angular2 project, and run npm start, the server will start, but after a while it will be down again.

Comment: I'm running out of answers ^^ Can you provide your code ?

Comment: Did you check if the is a Typo in your tsconfig.json ? (It happens to me all the time :) )

Comment: how can i do that? what is a typo?

Comment: Verify if you didn't write a mistake in your code. 'TYPO: informal a typographical error.'

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
} this is the tsconfig.json

Comment: found the problems, i had some TS errors in one of my components, and after i fixed them the server started, but i don't get it. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: tsc is the typescript compiler, so it's normal that `tsc -p ./src` failed because the compilation failed

Comment: Nah, no problem :)